# Catching the click on an iframe on the page hosting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a classic asp page which has an iframe.

I need to capture a click inside the iframe on the hosting classic asp page using javascript.

If I try this "Access is denied":

```
$(function(){
    $('#iframeElement')[0].contentWindow.document.onclick = function() {
        HandleIFrameClick();
    };
  });
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: do you control the content inside the iframe? If so, you could send a message to the parent using parent.[postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), then in your hosting page, observe 'message' on the window...

Comment: We do not control the content inside the iframe.